# 2nd MUX PCA9548A not showing up

Tags: i2c

Trying to add a 2nd MUX on bus 1 of my Room.
I added the following to the config.txt, essentially duplicating my original MUX with a second one, changing the address:

dtoverlay=i2c-mux,pca9548a,addr=0x70
dtoverlay=i2c-mux,pca9548a,addr=0x77

(First unit has a0-2 tied low, 2nd unit has all of them tied high)

After Reboot (including power cycle), the 2nd unit doesn't show up.

On i2cdetect -l, only the 8 ports of 0x70 show up (bus 22-29), when I would expect another 8 for 0x77.

It is confirmed working when I only use one overlay.

Any ideas? Cheers

BTW, 0x77 does show up in the address grid of 0x70...

Comment: is `pca9548a` a valid param for `i2c-mux`? the README only shows `pca9548`

Comment: What happens if you connect both, only configure 1 (and don't specify addr)? You have posted no diagnostics. Have you actually connected ANY modules to the MUX?

Comment: Apparently "a" was discontinued from tue options. I fixed that.

Comment: The problem was a typo in the dtoverlay. It now works. Note that the sequence of the dtoverlay lines matters. It starts assigning buses to the last line first... There was no easy way to force an address, but that is being fixed now. I'm betaing the version, where you can specify a "base" for each mix. So I can start mux1 at 0x30 and mux2 at 0x40. Much cleaner